# Проблема с анимацией в select

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, вёрстка, frontend

пытаюсь стилизовать select, хочу сделать анимацию, что при клике на select и выборе нужного option, border-bottom будет менять цвет, а еще лучше это будет анимация в рамках материал дизайн.

вот песочница https://codepen.io/ivan-volyk/pen/NVjJvZ

```
<select data-jcf='{"maxVisibleItems": 5}'>
    <option class="placeholder">placeholder</option>
    <option>html</option>
    <option>css</option>
    <option>js</option>
    <option>javascript</option>
    <option>angular</option>
    <option>react</option>
    <option>vue</option>
    <option>babel</option>
    <option>gulp</option>
    <option>git</option>
    <option>github</option>
    <option>gitlab</option>
    <option>opera</option>
    <option>chrome</option>
    <option>mozilla</option>
    <option>safari</option>
    <option>vivaldi</option>
    <option>saas</option>
    <option>less</option>
    <option>bootstrap</option>
    <option>random</option>
    <option>web</option>
    <option>python</option>
    <option>jquery</option>
    <option>php</option>
    <option>ruby</option>
</select>
```

кто-то шарит подобные штуки?

Comment: Кто-то шарит.. В чём проблема, собственно? За вас анимацию написать надо?

Comment: с каких пор изменение цвета - это анимация?? возьмите просто в js замените цвет по селектору при нажатии

Comment: Стилизовать нативный select - дохлый номер. Все может отличаться от браузера к браузеру.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, стандартный select практически не стилизуется при помощи css. Если вы хотите добавить определенные эффекты к элементам выпадающего списка либо анимировать его "выпадение", то вам необходимо написать собственный список вручную на js, либо использовать готовые библиотеки на подобии [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/).